# How to get a single property of all children in a nested object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, javascript-objects

For an interactive map which shows countries' data over time (using d3), I have a single large object called `dataset`. The properties of `dataset` are again objects identified by a country's name. The next level are objects, again, indicated by the year. The last level finally is the data to be displayed.
The structure is something like this:

```
dataset
    - CountryA
        - 2010
            - population: 4000000
            - crime rate: 17.4
            - GDP per capita: 2800
        - 2011 
            - population: 4100000
            - crime rate: 16.8
            - GDP per capita: 2900
        - ...
    - CountryB
        - 2010
            - population: 3700000
            - crime rate: 25.6
            - GDP per capita: 1200
        - 2011 
            - population: 3850000
            - crime rate: 27.2
            - GDP per capita: 1180
        - ...
    - ...
```

Now, for updating the map, I need to find the range for a specific property in order to adapt the color range I want to use. For example, if I want to get the minimum and maximum values for crime rates in the year 2010, is there an easy command to retrieve that information?

I do have a list of all available countries and can of course loop through that list and get the value for specified year, compare it to a global min/max value and change it if necessary (using `Math.min/max`). I am just wondering, if I there is an easy way to that, like

```
var crimeRateLow = getGlobalMin(dataset, 2, "crime rate");

// magic function
function getGlobalMin(object, unspecifiedLevels, indicator) { ... }
```

I am currently using the following function with `j` being the indicator and the `year` is a globally set variable:

```
function getRange(j) {
  var jRange = {"min": 0, "max": 0};
  for (k in dataset) {
    jRange["min"] = Math.min(jRange["min"], dataset[k][year][j]);
    jRange["max"] = Math.max(jRange["max"], dataset[k][year][j]);
  }
  return jRange;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is no built-in function in d3 addressing your problem, d3 might help to solve it elegantly.

1. De-nest your nested object into smaller arrays containing the field values of interest by repeatedly applying [`d3.values()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_values) to get an array of property values (still objects) of the associative array. These property values/objects are afterwards [`mapped`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to arrays containing just the field values of interest.
2. Merge these arrays using [`d3.merge()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_merge) into one large array.
3. Apply [`d3.extent()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent) to obtain the global extent (i.e. array `[min,max`]) from it.

   ```
   function getGlobalExtent(data, field) {
       return d3.extent(     // (3.) Get the global extent.
           d3.merge(     // (2.) Merge all arrays into a single one.
               d3.values(data)     // (1.) Array of all country objects in dataset
                   .map(function(country) {     // (1.) Map each country to array of field values for all years within.
                           return d3.values(country)     // (1.) Array of years in each country
                                       .map(function(year) {     // (1.) Map each year to the requested field value.
                                           return year[field];
                                       });
                   })
           )
       );
   }
   ```

I put together a working snippet:

```js
var dataset = {
    "CountryA": {
        "2010": {
            "population": 4000000,
            "crime rate": 17.4,
            "GDP per capita": 2800
        },
        "2011": {
            "population": 4100000,
            "crime rate": 16.8,
            "GDP per capita": 2900
        }
    },
    "CountryB": {
        "2010": {
            "population": 3700000,
            "crime rate": 25.6,
            "GDP per capita": 1200
        },
        "2011": {
            "population": 3850000,
            "crime rate": 27.2,
            "GDP per capita": 1180
        }
    }
};

function getGlobalExtent(data, field) {
    return d3.extent(     // (3.) Get the global extent.
        d3.merge(     // (2.) Merge all arrays into a single one.
            d3.values(data)     // (1.) Array of all country objects in dataset
                .map(function(country) {     // (1.) Map each country to array of field values for all years within.
                        return d3.values(country)     // (1.) Array of years in each country
                                    .map(function(year) {     // (1.) Map each year to the requested field value.
                                        return year[field];
                                    });
                })
        )
    );
}

// population: 3700000,4100000
//console.log("population:", getGlobalExtent(dataset, "population").join());

// crime rate: 16.8,27.2
//console.log("crime rate:", getGlobalExtent(dataset, "crime rate").join());

// GDP per capita: 1180,2900
//console.log("GDP per capita:", getGlobalExtent(dataset, "GDP per capita").join());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```